# Listbox in VBA apply selection on per row basis

Tags: vba, ms-access

In access 2010 I am trying to create a listbox in a form.  Once I make a selection for a row in the form, the listbox automatically assigns those values to all the rows instead of on a per row basis.

Does anybody know how to change this option such that the listbox assigns the values per row?

I am doing this via the clickable solutions since I do not know any VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the listbox is *unbound* - then the value selected is common for all visible records.

So, create a field in the table used as source for the form. Then *bind* the listbox to this field.